# Loading modules via webpack in typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

I just started the course of Typescript-fundamentals. I've got a problem to load modules via webpack. I'm using webstorm  and when I type "yarn dev-server"  on the terminal it saying :"error Command "dev-server" not found."  I'll  appreciate If someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

if `dev-server` is a script defined in package.json then you should run it using `yarn run dev-server` command